# Is it possible to manually run a GitHub workflow?

Tags: github-actions

GitHub actions are a great way to program in "DevOps teams". But sometimes you have to run automated workflows when certain criteria is met.

My team is using GitHub actions for the automated tasks which is to be performed when new code enters the repositories and we have a server running Jenkins to perform manual automated tasks.

It would be great to have all our automated tasks written using the same standard.

Is it possible to manually execute an automated GitHub workflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually trigger a Github action workflow if it contains the `workflow_dispatch` trigger.

You can find more information about how to do it through the Github UI in [the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/pt/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow).

**Note that:**

- You can even trigger those workflow with a request to the Github API using the [Create a workflow dispatch event service](https://docs.github.com/pt/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event)
- Those workflows triggered manually can also receive inputs.

---

Here is an example of a `workflow_dispatch` workflow with an input parameter:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      input:
        description: "Test"
        required: false
        default: "World"

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo Hello ${{ github.event.inputs.input }}
```

[Workflow runs of this workflow can be found here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/workflows/00-workflow-dispatch-input.yml)

Comment: english docs: [Create a workflow dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event) and [List workflow runs for a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-workflow-runs-for-a-workflow)