# Unable to run a github action which resides on a feature franch

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to run a github action which resides on a feature branch, don't seem to have much luck. I have had to disable the job as what seems to have been happening is that when users check into the main branch, it runs the action. I only want it to run manually on demand and not via a push.

we  have the main branch, and this action currently re sides on the workspace_publish branch, If I try to run it, its disabled and i get the message `Workflow does not exist or does not have a workflow_dispatch trigger in this branch`

```
name: workspace deployment 
on:
  # push:
    # branches: [workspace_publish]

  workflow_dispatch: 

jobs:

  release:

    runs-on: ubuntu
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        name: Synapse workspace deployment
      - uses: azure/synapse-workspace-deployment@release-1.0
        with:
          TargetWorkspaceName: 'my-workspace'
          TemplateFile: './synapse-1/TemplateForWorkspace.json'
          ParametersFile: './synapse-1/TemplateParametersForWorkspace.json'
          environment: 'Azure Public'
          resourceGroup: 'my-rg'
          clientId: ${{secrets.CLIENTID}}
          clientSecret: ${{secrets.CLIENTSECRET}}
          subscriptionId: ${{secrets.SUBSCRIPTIONID}}
          tenantId: ${{secrets.TENANTID}}
          DeleteArtifactsNotInTemplate: 'False'
          managedIdentity: 'False'
```

Having followed the instructions on [Github Actions: how to run a workflow created on a non-master branch from the workflow_dispatch event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63362126/github-actions-how-to-run-a-workflow-created-on-a-non-master-branch-from-the-wo) the answer proposed by the user piotrekkr. I cannot run the action when choosing a feature branch (workspace_publish). Not sure what is wrong in this case. It only works when main is the selected branch, that fails as the files are not present on main.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Workflows using the `workflow_dispatch` need to be present on the repo `default` branch to appear on the `Actions` tab and be available to trigger manually through the UI. If this `workspace deployment` isn't on the default branch, only on the `workspace_publish` branch, it won't appear (note that once it's on the default branch, you can have different implementations for this workflow on other branches)

Comment: when you say it needs to be on the default branch, do you mean duplicate it and place it on the main branch ? I believe I read something similar and tried to do this, but what w as happening is that when the dev team commit changes, it kept running the action which was not what was intended, so i deleted it. Also for the action to work, it needs to reference files on the `workspace_publish` branch, that was another reason why i deleted it, everytime it ran it failed because it couldn't find the files on the main branch.

Comment: I mean it to be on the main branch as well as on the other branch, yes. That way, it will appear on the Actions tab and you'll be able to trigger it manually selecting the `workspace_publish` branch. Are you only triggering the workflow run manually, or are you automating it through a request to the Github API as well? Because if it's specifically for this branch, you can also remove the `workflow_dispatch` trigger and always run it on `push` on the `workspace_publish` branch (like it's commented on the example you shared).

Comment: still a little confused, what I have done is have the code on the main branch and on the workspace_publish branch, when i click on the action tab, I can see the action and It can run it manually only from main, but it will fail because the file it needs is on workspace_publish, if i choose the workspace_publish branch, the run workflow button is disabled.

Comment: You should be able to run this workflow from the `Actions` tab for both branches. When clicking on the [`Run Workflow` button](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/manually-running-a-workflow), the `workspace_publish` branch should appear (otherwise it would mean the workflow isn't configured with a `workflow_dispatch` trigger on the specified branch).

Comment: I have edited my question to avoid a long comment section, clearly something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: Is this `workspace deployment` workflow on the `workspace_publish` branch as well, and configure with a `workflow_dispatch` trigger?

Comment: Yes it is, I'm unsure as to what to do now.

Comment: Strange. According to the picture you shared, the `workspace_publish` branch seems indeed to be there, but doesn't seem to have this `workspace deployment` workflow file, or  the `workflow_dispatch` configuration set on the workflow YAML file (at least not updated on the Github UI for that branch).

Answer (score 0):

To run the manually use `workflow_dispatch:` and add some `inputs`

Eg:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      input:
        description: "Type `run me` to execute"
        required: true # or false
      ...
```

And later you can use the if statement to check the value entered

Eg:

```
jobs:
  analyze:
    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.input == 'run me' }}
    name: Analyze code
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    ...
```

Check this for more details

[Is it possible to manually run a GitHub workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60419257/is-it-possible-to-manually-run-a-github-workflow)

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/manually-running-a-workflow